# Combine multiple php bootstrap alert box into one

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, alert

i have a form which show error inside bootstrap `alert`, if username exist and if email exist. like in picture

[image]

now my question in how do i show alert in **one single alert box**

code

```
      if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) {
            $error[] = 'Username is too short.';
        } else {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('Database query');
            if (!empty($row['username'])) {
                $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
            }
        } 
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        } else {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('Database query');

            if (!empty($row['email'])) {
                $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
            }
        }

        / alert box
        if (isset($error)) {
            foreach ($error as $errors) {
                   echo "<div class='alert alert-danger small text-center' role='alert'>" . $error . "</div>";
                     }
            }
              if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined') {
                   echo "<div class='alert alert-success small text-center' role='alert'>Registration successful.<br> Please check your email to activate your account.</div>";
        }
```

i tried adding `$error[] .=` but still din't work, any solution.

this is how i want my alert box to be

[image]

Comment: If you want them all in one box, then the code for the box itself of course belongs outside the loop …

Comment: Instead of `foreach` try: `echo "<div class='alert alert-danger small text-center' role='alert'>" . implode('<br>', $errors) . "</div>";`

Comment: @AlonEitan i tried replacing `foreach` and i get these error `Undefined variable: errors` and `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: @sanojlawrence I got confused with the variable names, should be `implode('<br>', $error)` - I also fixed the same bug in the answer below so it should work for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

if (strlen($_POST['username']) < 3) {
    $error[] = 'Username is too short.';
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('Database query');
    if (!empty($row['username'])) {
        $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
    }
}
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('Database query');

    if (!empty($row['email'])) {
        $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
    }
}

// alert box
if (isset($error)) {
    $errorMsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger small text-center' role='alert'><ul>";
    foreach ($error as $errors) {
        $errorMsg .= '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
    }
    $errorMsg .= '</ul></div>';
    echo $errorMsg;
}
```

Comment: i get this error `Array to string conversion in C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OLX\register.php on line 110` and line 110 is `$errorMsg .= '<li>' . $error . '</li>';`

Comment: i don't see any alert box, when i try your.

Comment: @sanojlawrence I fixed another small issue in this answer and it should work, if it does the you can accept it (It was just missing `echo $errorMsg;`)